# Odoo- Hide field for multiple groups OR visible to multiple groups

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

e. The issue i am facing is that i need to show a field to multiple user groups. I know how to show field to one group

```
<field name="received_qty" groups="base.test_group" string="Total Received Quantity"/>
```

but i want to show this field to multiple groups `(suppose :'base.group1','base.group2')` and then it should be hidden from all other groups which are not listed here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `,` operator we can give groups name in field as many as we want.

For example:

```
groups="base.test_group,base.test_group1,base.test_group2"
```

It's combination of *module_name.xml_group_id.* Field can be visible for those User who has group checked.

Comment: what if i want this field to be invisible for multiple groups because in attrs="{'invisible':groups}" is not allowed

Comment: For that you can make one function field which will return True if you want to display that field User otherwise False. Afterwards, that field give in *attrs=*